# Unable to use array's method "find" in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to get current location of a user and then push it into array. Before I do so, I check whether a city with the same name is already there. In that case, I won't push it into the array. However, when I am trying to check it, it says: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'find').

```
const found = ref(false);
const weatherResponse = ref([]);

function getLocation() {
  console.log("SETTING LOCATION");
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    console.log(`Lat: ${position.coords.latitude}, Lon: ${position.coords.longitude}`);
    if (position.coords.latitude && position.coords.longitude) {
      axios.get(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${API_KEY}&q=${Math.round(position.coords.latitude)},${Math.round(position.coords.longitude)}&aqi=no`)
        .then((response) => {
          found.value = weatherResponse.value.find((item) => item.location.name == response.data.location.name);

          if (response.data?.error?.code != 1006 && !found.value) {
            weatherResponse.value.push(response.data);
            this.$store.commit("addToList", response.data);
            console.log(weatherResponse.value);
          }
        })
    }
  },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  )
}
```

I've already tried using fetch, axios to grab the API, but the "find()" method is still not working. Regarding "found" variable, I tried using it in ref as well as declaring it as "let found".

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: there's no problem with your usage of `weatherResponse` array in the provided snippet.  are you perhaps changing `weatherResponse` somewhere else in your code? setting it to null or some other type that isn't an array?

Comment: @yoduh I am using `weatherResponse.push` and `weather.response.splice`, but in different functions.

Comment: The issue still very likely resides outside of the `getLocation` function.  Throwing just the provided code so far into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-danilo-d4mtww?file=/src/App.vue) doesn't produce any error (I took out the axios call but that shouldn't have any relation to the error you're seeing).  We'll need to see more of your component code to find the root cause.  If you can reproduce the error in a sandbox that'd be even better.

Comment: What is the value of `weatherResponse.value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and testing, I've finally managed to get everything to work. My issue was in (weirdly) `main.js`. Because it was set out like this: `createApp(App).use(cors, store).mount('#app')` it, I guess, caused VueX.store not to load in properly because mounted hook was called and it was throwing all sorts of mistakes. Putting it like `const app = createApp(App);  app.use(store); app.use(cors);  app.mount("#app");` actually made it work.